# Does java Socket's auto reconnect when you call .close()?

Tags: java

I was wondering if java Socket's auto reconnect to a server if you call .close() on the client side? I been trying to write a little piece of software and I have a .disconnect() function that closes the connection. But when I call .disconnect() it logs out what it would when connecting...

Comment: It doesn't reconnect at at all, whether automatically or otherwise, at `close()` or any other time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Socket API documentation: "Once a socket has been closed, it is not available for further networking use (i.e. can't be reconnected or rebound). A new socket needs to be created."

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#close--

Comment: Thank you! i feel dumb for not looking at the doc's I'm just trying to debug my problem here because it seems to be reconnecting :/